# how to show the contents in one ui using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to framework, the no.of contents are getting overloaded. the problem is when we have multiple users then their name need to be displayed according to the content of the message, for that we need to give mapping at first, but the data is getting overloaded.

Can anyone help me in this query?

Here is the code:

```
    <div>
        {this.state.data.map(item => {
          return (
            <Card>
              <CardHeader
                avatar={<div>Sanjana (or) someone else</div>}
                title={
                  <>
                    <InputBase
                      placeholder="Search Google Maps"
                      margin="normal"
                    />
                    <IconButton type="submit" aria-label="search">
                      <SearchIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </>
                }
              />
              <Divider />
              <CardContent className={classes.contentHeight} id="chatList">
                <div>
                  <Message isSender content={item.message} />
                  <Message content={item.message} />
                </div>
              </CardContent>
              <Divider />
              <CardActions>
                <Paper className={classes.contentPaper}>
                  <Input
                    margin="dense"
                    className={classes.input}
                    placeholder="Enter a Message"
                    disableUnderline
                  />
                </Paper>
              </CardActions>
            </Card>
          );
        })}
      </div>
```

Can anyone help me in this? thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you be more detailed and/or specific about what you mean when you say "but the data is getting overloaded"? What isn't working as expected? What is the expected result?

Comment: @DrewReese - Could you please preview the code snippet i provided in my query so that it may help you to understand my query

Comment: I did, and it wasn't clear what was wrong, but you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of code **and** specifically state what isn't working, what you've tried, and what your expected result should be.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to only map the data messages, not the chat container(s)

```
render() {
  const { classes } = this.props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Card>
        <CardHeader
          avatar={<div>Sanjana (or) someone else</div>}
          title={
            <>
              <InputBase placeholder="Search Google Maps" margin="normal" />
              <IconButton type="submit" aria-label="search">
                <SearchIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </>
          }
        />
        <Divider />
        <CardContent className={classes.contentHeight} id="chatList">
          {this.state.data.map(item => {
            return (
              <div>
                <Message isSender content={item.message} />
                <Message content={item.message} />
              </div>
            );
          })}
        </CardContent>
        <Divider />
        <CardActions>
          <Paper className={classes.contentPaper}>
            <Input
              margin="dense"
              className={classes.input}
              placeholder="Enter a Message"
              disableUnderline
            />
          </Paper>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit nifty-architecture-e3xci]

Comment: I've tried the above one but our requirement is not to give map function in the middle (not only for messages), it should place at the beginning for the name also (Where i wrote `My Name` from there map function should begin) Inorder to get respective users name

Comment: @Sanjana What else is there to map? It doesn't make any sense to map the header and action for each message. Is there supposed to be some other data array of users and each outer map would a separate conversation?

Comment: For the content of messages we will have a specific name right? for example if i'm texting you then the header should have your name. I hope i could clear your query with this example. I mean as per the name of the user, i have to get the content. Moreover i have no idea, how to give name in the json. that's the reason i made json for ony the content

Comment: For your your question and code, no. As it stands, there's only a single json object in your code to map over and based upon its contents it appears to be a single conversation between two people. Can you update your question and codesandbox to produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of this scenario?